# TYPO3 remove cache comment for json view

Tags: json, api, caching, typo3

I want to have a json output of my page, so I have a typoscript setup with
diableAllHeaderCode and additionalHeaders Content-Type: application/json
Everything is good for the first call after clearing caches, but after that the json format is invalid because typo3 adds a comment to the bottom of the page like `<!-- Cached page generated _-_-_ _:_. Expires _-_-_ _:_ -->`
Can I somehow remove that tag or prevent it from being rendered without blocking the whole caching mechanism ?
And I would like to not change the TypoScriptFrontendController.php directly but rather find a solution to manage this from my extension

Comment: Make the page uncached and also include your ext as `USER_INT` instead of  `USER` in TS (or `COA_INT` depending what you're using)

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but why should I uncache it, I want to serve blog data, etc. to another site kind of  like a headless CMS approach, so I defenitely want caching to be active, as this leads to way faster fetch requests or am I missing something here?

Comment: Not whole service, just page, that serves your JSON, or I'm missing something.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot I'll check that and do some speed testing, Thanks ;)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, no_cache is not a valid option as this increases the loading time (fetch request) of the external page accessing the resources, it takes about twice as long as with cashing.

Comment: Here is a good example with all recommended options: https://docs.typo3.org/p/extcode/cart/6.8/en-us/AdministratorManual/Configuration/AjaxConfiguration/Index.html (the no_cache is up to you of course). I am adding a ticket to have a AJAX-by-pagetype example added to the TYPO3 docs: https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Reference-Typoscript/issues/421.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is displayed only for development/debug environment.

Dependend on your TYPO3 version you could try to disable this kind of debugging with some typoscript:

either global with `config.debug = 0`
or specific for your pagetype you use to generate JSON: `json.config.debug = 0` (assumed this page object is named `json`)

Otherwise you test your JSON on the production system.
or you save your output, remove the comment and feed the file to your further process.

Comment: Yep, you are genius, thank you very much, I didn't put this under the category of debug information but seems logic now that I know it, thanks a lot.